# How to get Adapter properties of a remote computer (IP address or host name) using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and want to know how to get Adapter properties of a remote computer (IP address or host name).
Host computer also has a user name and password.

I found this one but unsure how to use as per my requirements as i am new to powershell.

```
Get-NetAdapter -CimSession $cim -physical |
    Select Name, LinkSpeed |
    Out-GridView -title NetworkAdapters
```

I am sure that this is completely wrong.

Comment: There's also [Get-NetIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Comment: What are your requirements? What's the output supposed to look like

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala
Requirement : I need to get Network Adapter properties of a remote computer (username: support password:123456)
Get-NetAdapter | Select Name, LinkSpeed is the command i am running for local computer
I need to run same command for a remote computer

Comment: Look into `invoke-command`, it supports  alternate credentials specifying the `-Credential` parameter. That should be all you need. As an alternative you can look into the `Get-CimInstance` *cmdlets* that have a `-ComputerName` parameter as well. You just have to query the right namespace/class.

Answer (score 0):

These commands that you have specified are correct.
You can look for more details: http://woshub.com/powershell-configure-windows-networking/